# How to clear a PyListObject?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I have a question that how to clear a list that's formed by `PyList_Append()`?
Is there a document about Python/C extension API functions in detail?

Comment: Thanks, but another question.

PyObject *newlist = PyList_New(0);
PyObject *subList = PyList_New(0);
PyList_Append(subList, PyString_FromString("first"));
PyList_Append(subList, PyString_FromString("second"));
PyList_Append(subList, PyString_FromString("third"));
PyList_SetSlice(subList, 0, PyList_Size(subList), NULL);
PyList_Append(subList, PyString_FromFormat("abcdef"));
PyList_Append(newlist, subList);
now I get [['abcdef'],['abcdef']]. The initial strings "first" and "second" are override. How to solve it?
Sorry I don't know how to edit the format. Maybe I need a tutorial.

Answer (score 7):

IIRC you have to use [`PyList_SetSlice`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html#PyList_SetSlice):

```
PyList_SetSlice(your_list, 0, PyList_Size(your_list), NULL);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [PySequence_DelSlice](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_DelSlice) function:

```
# The same as: del L[0:len(L)]
PySequence_DelSlice(L, 0, PySequence_Length(L));
```