# How to convert small integers in C with `PyLong_FromLong`?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes, python-c-api

I have been writing C code that I need to call from Python3. The C file compiles fine and I can import with `ctypes` `CDLL` command. Most functions work fine and I can call them from Python. I am using Python version 3.9.16.

However, I am having problems converting and manipulating small integers. I understand that Python3 uses objects for integers between -5 and 256. If I try to convert longs of this size to `PyObject` in my code the script crashes.

Here's an example function in my C file:

```
PyObject*
convert_long_to_pyobject(long lng)
{
    return PyLong_FromLong(lng);
}
```

If I call that from Python with the following, the second call to the function will cause a crash:

```
from ctypes import CDLL, c_long, py_object
dk = CDLL(my_path)

dk.convert_long_to_pyobject.argtypes = [c_long]
dk.convert_long_to_pyobject.restype = py_object

dk.convert_long_to_pyobject(257) # returns 257
dk.convert_long_to_pyobject(256) # crashes
```

I haven't written a full C extension. I've just written some functions in a C file, compiled it then loaded with `CDLL`. I've seen that there is a function called `Py_Initialize` which maybe sets up the objects for integers in the range (-5, 256) but as far as I can see it is meant for full extensions (and when I tried adding it into a function before a call to `PyLong_FromLong` it didn't solve my problem.

So my question is, what do I need to do to be able to handle small integers as PyObjects in C? Particularly to convert them between C and Python.

Edit: I was previously running this from Rmarkdown which was hiding the fault returned in Python. The fault returned on the final call to the function within Python is:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Please add the details of the crash - does the entire Python program crash?  Does it throw an exception?

Comment: Also pease update your python version.

Comment: I don't think this has anything (directly) to do with caching, but with accurately reflecting the reference count of the object you return.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have no details of the crash. I'm actually calling it from an Rmarkdown with `reticulate` and it causes my R session to abort with 'R encountered a fatal error'. I'm new to C and haven't yet figured out how to connect the outputs to Console on my Mac.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I am using Python 3.9.16.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I opened Python and ran the code above; the fault when using 256 is: `Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51954484/4657412 - you need t use `PyDll` when calling C API functions

Comment: @DavidW Yes, thanks, that fixed the problem; for anyone reading this; just change all references from `CDLL` to `PyDLL` in the Python code.

Comment: You really should show your whole code because I don’t think you’re doing anything you’re supposed to be doing. You don’t need to use python C APIs to call C functions with ctypes

Comment: @MarkTolonen I can't show the code but I need to handle PyObjects such as Python dictionaries after they are passed to a C function. I needed to extract numerical values from a dictionary and increment them, which required a conversion from a PyObject to an int and back to a PyObject, which failed because PyLong_FromLong would error if the int was in the small ints range.

Comment: In that case, PyDLL has to be used for any function that uses Python C APIs because it doesn’t release the GIL, unlike CDLL and WinDLL.